# jenkins build is getting failed all the time when i run with the command mvn

Tags: maven, jenkins

i had a problem with build when i build its coming as a fail first i thought it was maven version but changed then java version changed but its not getting the build is getting failed when i put executive shell -mvn package

```
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/parasahithi1/simple-java-maven-app.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision dc32cee767f79f3f9db1efa643475990dccd580c (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f dc32cee767f79f3f9db1efa643475990dccd580c # timeout=10
Commit message: "Create 123"
 > git rev-list --no-walk dc32cee767f79f3f9db1efa643475990dccd580c # timeout=10
[dev1] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins16611573518334796924.sh
+ maven package
/tmp/jenkins16611573518334796924.sh: line 2: maven: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I see the error is:

```
maven: command not found
```

because the [`maven` command](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html#build-the-project) doesn't exist. I guess the right command to run should be:

```
mvn package
```

Comment: `maven` was the command for [maven 1.0](https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/), long since abandoned.